# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException when I run jetty

Tags: jetty, cdi, weld

I try to run a deployment of an app with jetty 9.4.8. It is an angular java maven multi module app

Here is my web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <display-name>Tourism Applicationwith Angular</display-name>
    <description>
        This is a simple web application with a source code organization
        based on the recommendations of the Application Developer's Guide.
    </description>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>


    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
  </listener>

   <listener>
    <listener-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
        </listener-class>
  </listener>



      <resource-env-ref>
        <description>Object factory for the CDI Bean Manager</description>
        <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
        <resource-env-ref-type>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</resource-env-ref-type>
      </resource-env-ref>    

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>webservice.TourismWebService</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

I expose the CDI bean manager through JNDI by creating jetty-env.xml under WEB-INF (http://www.agorava.org/news/2012/07/10/Starting-a-CDI-webapp-from-Maven-with-Weld-servlet-and-jetty-plugin/)

```xml
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">
<Configure id="webAppCtx" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <New id="BeanManager" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
        <Arg>
            <Ref id="webAppCtx"/>
        </Arg>
        <Arg>BeanManager</Arg>
        <Arg>
            <New class="javax.naming.Reference">
                <Arg>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</Arg>
                <Arg>org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory</Arg>
                <Arg/>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </New>
</Configure>
```

To allow Jetty to load the server Classes, I create the file jetty-web.xml under WEB-INF (http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Reference/Jetty_Classloading)

```xml
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Set name="serverClasses">
        <Array type="java.lang.String">
            <Item>-org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.Decorator</Item>
        </Array>
    </Set>
   <Call name="prependServerClass">
      <Arg>-org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.listener.IntrospectorCleaner</Arg>
   </Call>   
   <Call name="prependServerClass">
      <Arg>-org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.listener.ELContextCleaner</Arg>
   </Call>    
   <Call name="prependServerClass">
      <Arg>-org.eclipse.jetty.util.Decorator</Arg>
   </Call>
   <Call name="prependServerClass">
      <Arg>-org.eclipse.jetty.util.DecoratedObjectFactory</Arg>
   </Call>
   <Call name="prependServerClass">
      <Arg>-org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.</Arg>
   </Call>
   <Call name="prependServerClass">
      <Arg>-org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler</Arg>
   </Call>
   <Call name="prependServerClass">
      <Arg>-org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler</Arg>
   </Call>
</Configure>
```

And when I run jetty, I have the following error message

```
2018-11-17 21:12:25.554:INFO:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main: Scanning elapsed time=19249ms
2018-11-17 21:12:25.927:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:main: NO JSP Support for /tourism-services, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
2018-11-17 21:12:25.940:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@548b7f67{/tourism-services,[file:/Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Services/target/tourism-services/],UNAVAILABLE}
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.visit(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.process(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaData.resolve(MetaData.java:408)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1475)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:785)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:418)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at runjettyrun.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:89)
Caused by: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/List
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$Context.createInstance(ContextHandler.java:2535)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor.newListenerInstance(StandardDescriptorProcessor.java:1965)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor.visitListener(StandardDescriptorProcessor.java:1914)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.visit(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.process(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaData.resolve(MetaData.java:408)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1475)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:785)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:418)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at runjettyrun.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:89)
Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.util.List
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.findClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:527)
    at runjettyrun.ProjectClassLoader.loadClass(ProjectClassLoader.java:92)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$Context.createInstance(ContextHandler.java:2535)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor.newListenerInstance(StandardDescriptorProcessor.java:1965)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor.visitListener(StandardDescriptorProcessor.java:1914)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.visit(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.process(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaData.resolve(MetaData.java:408)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1475)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:785)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:418)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at runjettyrun.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:89)
2018-11-17 21:12:26.054:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@11531931{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2018-11-17 21:12:26.058:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @21810ms
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `<Set>` against the `serverClasses` as it's undoing all of the existing (and required) settings for `serverClasses` to function properly.

Remove this section ...

```xml
<Set name="serverClasses">
    <Array type="java.lang.String">
        <Item>-org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.Decorator</Item>
    </Array>
</Set>
```

You should limit your modifications of `serverClasses` to calls that [`prependServerClass`](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/9.4.14.v20181114/org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppContext.html#prependServerClass-java.lang.String-) or [`addServerClass`](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/9.4.14.v20181114/org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/WebAppContext.html#addServerClass-java.lang.String-) to the existing list.

Examples:

```xml
<Call name="prependServerClass">
  <Arg>-org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler</Arg>
</Call>
<!-- or -->
<Call name="addServerClass">
  <Arg>-org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler</Arg>
</Call>
```

Comment: Hello Joakim, thank you for your answer. It solved my issue. However I have another error

Comment: By the way is it possible to have the text edit options for comment as we have it for answers ?